# borders around grids using css grids

Tags: css, frameworks, grid

What is the best way to apply a border and padding to a containing site wrap div to a site using a grid system like twitter-bootstrap ?

Using bootstrap for example - the grid depends on being within nested containers and rows. Applying a border and padding to the 1st container changes the maths and the contained divs stack vertically - the grid breaks.

placing the 1st container in a seperate wrap div and applying border & padding to the wrap div doesn't work either - the contained divs break out of the container.

so an example of the mark up is:

```
<div class=' main'>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='span12'>              
            <h1>Demo</h1>    
            <div class='row'>
              <section class='span8'>
                blah blah
              </section>
              <aside class='row'>
                links n stuff
              </aside>    
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

and i want to apply a 20 px padding, 1px border  to the main wrapper.  Bootstrap calculates the widths of spans in px's - so they are breaking out.

Comment: In order to get an answer it's best to supply some actual code that you are having problems with. A quick blind answer for me though would be that your second idea would probably work, you'd just need to make sure you have the right css on your wrapping element to combat `floats` or `positioned` children breaking out. For floats you can usually use `float:left` or `overflow:hidden`. For positioned elements you can use `position:relative`.

Comment: Ok, ill edit the question with some code, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so we don't want px widths, we want % widths.  Other frameworks use %'s.  oh.  bootstrap fluid uses %'s

```
<div class=' main'>
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row-fluid'>
    <div class='span12'>              
        <h1>Demo</h1>    
        <div class='row-fluid'>
          <section class='span8'>
            blah blah
          </section>
          <aside class='span3'>
            links n stuff
          </aside>    
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then work out the width of the container using media queries

```
.main{
  width:1210px;
  margin:20px auto;

  border-radius:3px;
  border:1px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(6,6,6,0.5);
}


@media (max-width: 1210px) { 
 .main{
    width:80%;
  }
 }
```

and thats a box around the bootstrap grid.  yay.